# Object.keys duplicating object in the array es6

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6

I have an object structure like this:

```
vKzGBlblU7hVqIildUIb:
characters: (2) [{…}, {…}]
created_by: "test1234"
deleted_at: null
genre: ""
key: "vKzGBlblU7hVqIildUIb"
main_character: ""
number_of_characters: 2
status: "draft"
summary: "Summary 23"
title: "Titile 23"
uploaded_at: 1531686836601
```

I tried to convert this object to an array using `Object.keys` but I end up with 2 objects inside an array. One containing the inner array `characters` and the other object not containing the array `characters`. I get something like this.

```
0:
    characters: (2) [{…}, {…}]
    created_by: "test1234"
    deleted_at: null
    genre: ""
    key: "vKzGBlblU7hVqIildUIb"
    main_character: ""
    number_of_characters: 2
    status: "draft"
    summary: "Summary 23"
    title: "Titile 23"
    uploaded_at: 1531686836601

1:
    created_by: "test1234"
    deleted_at: null
    genre: ""
    key: "vKzGBlblU7hVqIildUIb"
    main_character: ""
    number_of_characters: 2
    status: "draft"
    summary: "Summary 23"
    title: "Titile 23"
    uploaded_at: 1531686836601
```

This is how I am trying to convert the object to an array.

```
const array = Object.keys(objs).map((obj, index) => {
      return objs[obj]
    });
```

I don't understand what I am doing wrong. Any suggestions?

**UPDATE:**
The object structure is simple:

```
{
    vKzGBlblU7hVqIildUIb: {
        characters: [{
            name: "",
            id: ""
        }]
        key: "vKzGBlblU7hVqIildUIb"
        //other props listed in the example above
    }
    irufsxKuw9I20pLDa6P7: {
        characters: [{
            name: "",
            id: ""
        }]
        key: "irufsxKuw9I20pLDa6P7"
        //other props listed in the example above
    }
    // so on
}
```

What I expected the `Object.keys` would do:

```
[
    0: {
        characters: [{
            name: "",
            id: ""
        }]
        key: "vKzGBlblU7hVqIildUIb"
        //other props listed in the example above
    }
    1: {
        characters: [{
            name: "",
            id: ""
        }]
        key: "irufsxKuw9I20pLDa6P7"
        //other props listed in the example above
    }

    // so on
]
```

but what's actually happening:

```
[
    0: {
        characters: [{
            name: "",
            id: ""
        }]
        key: "vKzGBlblU7hVqIildUIb"
        //other props listed in the example above
    }
    1: {
        characters: [{
            name: "",
            id: ""
        }]
        key: "irufsxKuw9I20pLDa6P7"
        //other props listed in the example above
    }
    2: {
        key: "vKzGBlblU7hVqIildUIb"
        //other props listed in the example above
    }
    3: {
        key: "irufsxKuw9I20pLDa6P7"
        //other props listed in the example above
    }
    // so on
]
```

The objects get duplicated. Once with the nested array and other time without that. I just don't want this duplication.

Comment: You might just use `Object.values` or `Object.entries` instead

Comment: Show us a real object, not a console representation that is useless to test against. Also show expected results. See [mcve]

Comment: updated the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var objs = {
    vKzGBlblU7hVqIildUIb: {
        characters: [{
            name: "",
            id: ""
        }],
        key: "vKzGBlblU7hVqIildUIb",
        created_by: "test1234",
        deleted_at: null,
        genre: "",
        main_character: "",
        number_of_characters: 2,
        status: "draft",
        summary: "Summary 23",
        title: "Titile 23",
        uploaded_at: 1531686836601
    },
    irufsxKuw9I20pLDa6P7: {
        characters: [{
            name: "",
            id: ""
        }],
        key: "irufsxKuw9I20pLDa6P7",
        created_by: "test1234",
        deleted_at: null,
        genre: "",
        main_character: "",
        number_of_characters: 2,
        status: "draft",
        summary: "Summary 12",
        title: "Titile 23434",
        uploaded_at: 1531686836601
    }
}


const array = Object.keys(objs).map((obj, index) => {
      return objs[obj]
    });
    
    console.log(array);
```

What's wrong here?

Comment: I was pushing the same objects in the array twice. A typo, my mistake. Looks like I need a coffee :(

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys), [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) or [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries):

```js
const obj={vKzGBlblU7hVqIildUIb:{characters:[{name:"",id:""}],key:"vKzGBlblU7hVqIildUIb"},irufsxKuw9I20pLDa6P7:{characters:[{name:"",id:""}],key:"irufsxKuw9I20pLDa6P7"}};

const v1 = Object.keys(obj).map(k => obj[k]);

const v2 = Object.values(obj);

const v3 = Object.entries(obj).map(([_,o]) => o);

console.log(v1);
console.log(v2);
console.log(v3);
```